# Passing Object.Attr to function

Tags: ibm-doors

Usually, a reference to an Object's Attribute Value returns that value.

```
Object o = current Object
display o."Object Text"
```

However, if I pass that reference to a function that expects a string parameter, I get an error.

```
string displaySomeString(string s) {
    display s   
}
Object o = current Object
displaySomeString(o."Object Text")
```

I get this result from the debugger:

> -E- DXL:  incorrect arguments for function (displaySomeString)
>
> -I- DXL: All done. Errors reported: 1. Warnings reported: 0.

What gives? How do I robustly pass an Attribute value into a function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suspicion. If you're passing the object attribute value directly in the function call--

```
displaySomeString(o.attr)
```

--instead try passing it with an empty string at the end:

```
displaySomeString(o.attr "")
```

Or set the attribute value as something like

```
string v = o.attr
```

and then pass v in as

```
displaysomeString(v)
```

and I think it might work. o.attr really isn't a string, but a derived type, and concatenating an empty string at the end casts it to a string.

Comment: Yeah, I can pass it via a dummy variable. I don't recall if the cast to string ( append "") solves it or not, but I tried that.

But both are ungainly. I'd much rather overload the function with the ability to handle attribute values as inputs, but I can't figure out what type it is (and C has no "variant" type).

Comment: If you get a good answer to this one over on the IBM forum, please bring it back here, I'd be interested to see it. This is one of those things in DXL (not a small list) that I've given up on and decided that That's Just How It Is and dealt with it. If there's a solution: great.

Comment: Kirk, I've giving up, too. It's just a DXL Weirdness(tm), courtesy of IBM. 

I've also given up on the practice of building up the parameters for function calls, like in 

_displaySomeString(o."Object Text" "")_

Instead, I use temp variables like:

_string s = o."Object Text" "";_
_displaySomeString(s)_
... mainly because the debugger gives me more specific feedback, and since this IDE is such a POS... every bit helps.

Comment: There are just some things in DOORS that are just like that... A big problem for me is that if I don't write anything in DXL for a few months, I forget all of these little potholes and run right into them again...

Comment: Kirk, you brought up an excellent point. I was actually trying to write a library of robust function calls (that would forgive mistakes like sending a char where a string was expected, etc) for common functions.

However, this is one I can't solve. I don't know how to write the overloaded version of f(string) as f(objectattributename). Obviously, that last isn't a real Type... But what is the Type? The DXL guide refers to a variable "attrDef", but in every instance specifies that this variable is actually of the form Object."Attribute Name" (IOW, there is not a single variable being used).